# Netplan config not working

Tags: networking, netplan

I migrated from Ubuntu 16 to 18.04, and now my Internet connectivity is broken. Problem seems to be that 18.04 is using `netplan` and it wasn't properly configured.

The file `/etc/network/interfaces` only contains the loopback device:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

All the other entries are commented out (probably by an installer script).

The directory `/etc/netplan/` was empty. I created a `01-netcfg.yaml` with the following contents:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: yes
      dhcp6: no
      # addresses: []
      gateway4: xxx.xx.xx.xxx
      nameservers:
        addresses: [xxx.xx.xx.xx, xxx.xx.xx.xx]
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
```

The command `sudo netplan --debug apply` reveals the following interesting lines:

```
NetworkManager: definition eth0 is not for us (backend 1)
DEBUG: eth0 not found in {}
```

While looking for solutions, I found that most people don't use `eth0` in their yaml definition, but something like `enp2s0`. Howerver, the command `ifconfig` shows only the two interfaces, `eth0` and `lo`. Same with `ip addr show`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a server system or a desktop system? if the latter, your interface is likely being rendered by `NetworkManager` already (hence "not for us")

Comment: It's a desktop system. I tried using renderer: NetworkManager also, but it didn't help.

Comment: For reference, what do you see if you run `dmesg|grep eth0` ? Are there any `renamed from eth0` lines ? Also, what's the output of `sudo journalctl -xeu networkd` and of `sudo journalctl -xeu NetworkManager` ? You may need to change the `resolveer` to `NetworkManager` as that's probably still be default since your upgrade from 16.04

Comment: Eth0 was not renamed. The output from journalctl is empty. How do I change the resolveer?

Comment: Sorry - `renderer`. But I see you already tried that. No typos when you tried, I take it....

Comment: (edited my first comment since I mistyped second journalctl command - do you indeed get no output when running journalctl agains `NetworkManager`?)

Comment: No, journalctl against NetworkManager shows quite a lot of entries.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95913/discussion-between-taifwa-and-digory-doo).

Answer (score 3):

Your `/etc/network/interfaces` looks fine.

Change your `/etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml` to the following code (and only this)... using `sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then, in `terminal`...

`sudo netplan generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply configuration

`reboot` # reboot the computer

Then use the standard Network Manager GUI to establish a wired/wireless connection.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was impatient and uninstalled netplan. I'm now back to resolv.conf, which works fine. So, I don't know if your answer would have solved the problem...

Comment: @digorydoo if you've resorted to manually editing /etc/resolv.conf then you're still doing it wrong. And by removing a portion of the OS, you've handicapped your system. Best to reinstall netplan and follow my answer.

Comment: This answer states that it's best to go back to the standard Network Manager (GUI). Am I the only one who does not find that satisfying?

Comment: @JoeEifert Desktop installations should normally be using NetworkManager. Server installations should use netplan. This user has an 18.04 desktop upgrade installation where netplan isn't working. And the user uninstalled netplan, so why not go back to using the NM GUI?

Comment: @heynnema Generally yes. But I supposed there was a reason for him to not go with the default. E.G. I want to teach my students how it's done with netplan and the network manager, but they are learning on ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @JoeEifert If you read closely, the OP upgraded from Ubuntu 16.xx to 18.04. Ubuntu 16 was a NetworkManager environment. Setting 18.04 back to NM makes it just like they're used to, and it's the way it got installed in a default 18.04 desktop environment. Satisfied yet?

Answer (score 0):

First, check the interface name

```
ls -l /sys/class/net (or) sudo lshw -class network
```

then if you have netplan files move it .bkp(format)

```
sudo netplan generate
```

It will automatically generate with the previous setting and interface name, make sure you have the same interface name. if not, change the interface name

```
sudo netplan try
sudo netplan apply
```

or

```
sudo reboot
```